# parfor slicing of cell array

Tags: matlab, slice, cell-array, parfor

While using `parfor` in MATLAB using cell arrays I stepped into a problem where I can't see any difference from working example code and my buggy line!

The modification of data can be done indipendently for each worker and I wanted to use the slicing of variables, like shown in [MathWorks Blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/)

```
A3 = cell(10,1);
parfor ix = 1:10
    for jx = 1:10
        A3{ix}(jx) = ix + jx;
    end
end
A3 = cell2mat(A3);
```

Im doing the exactly same first level indexing like in the example, but MATLAB can't classify it.

I want certain lines to be deleted: There are file Files with each lines Lines that are compared against some values in (for simplicity not shown) other loops. For each file a worker will be assigned.

```
parfor file=1:length(data(:,1))
    line= 1;
    length_line = length(data{file,1}(:,1));

    while line <= length_line && ... && ...
       % some more loops
           if (...)
              data{file,1}(line,:) = [];
              length_line= length_line - 1;
           end
       % end of some more loops
       line= line + 1;
    end
end
% data will be returned
```

I don't see why it should not work! What i took into account:

- `data` will be modified so that each workers modification has no cross influence to others ( deleted lines are only a subset part of actual worker data)
- for slicing indexing must be done in first level ( `data{file,1}` )
- other first level indexing variables will be treated as constant / are constants, I use "1" so everything is good.
- No in-parloop assignment of variables that later will be used outside (not even constants)
- Testing without the line `data{file,1}(line,:)= []` runs without Matlab warnings.
- Tried MATLAB static code analyser `output = mlint('myFile.m')` but it doesn't show me any useful hints.

Just this single line is breaking up everything. But I really need this command to work. Any hints / workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, I did not try it out, but this should fix it:

```
parfor file=1:length(data(:,1))
    line= 1;
    length_line = length(data{file,1}(:,1));
    dataslice=data{file,1}
    while line <= length_line && ... && ...
       % some more loops
           if (...)
              dataslice(line,:) = [];
              length_line= length_line - 1;
           end
       % end of some more loops
       line= line + 1;
    end
    data{file,1}=dataslice
end
% data will be returned
```

If this does not help, please update your question and provide a reproducable example (initialisation of all variables, complete code)

Comment: it works! really great, thank you =) But i don't understand why this makes a difference to matlab. Could you add a note for that?

Comment: The classification of variables is not well documented, but it's based on formal code analyse. These rules sometimes fail. The most prominent example is: `x=foo();y=cell(x,1);parfor ix=1:x...` is okay, but `y=cell(foo(),1);parfor ix=1:foo()...` fails in most cases when you try to slice y.